# c# WPF Cant get Parent Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf page hosted in a Window. But i get Null exception when i tries to get use this.
It works then i use this code in another method but not in alla methods why is it that way?
please advice.

```
 NewPage page = new NewPage ();
 Window w = Window.GetWindow(this.Parent);
 w.Content = page;
```

Edit:

heres the full code:

```
    public HandOverListPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        _settings = new Settings();
    }


    public void ShowCurrentInUseAssignment() {

        _currentDoc = (App.Current as App).SelectedHandOverDoc;

        var r = from item in (App.Current as App).SelectedHandOverDoc.Items
                where item.Status != 20
                select item;

        if(r.Count() == 0) {
            //Report assignment to QP with status finished
            ReportAssignment();

            HandOverPage page = new HandOverPage();

            Window w = Window.GetWindow(this.Parent);
            w.Content = page;

            return;
        } else {
            ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView((App.Current as App).SelectedHandOverDoc.Items);
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Status", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

            ListBoxAssignmentItems.ItemsSource = view;
        }

        TxtBlockCounter.Text = r.Count().ToString();
    }
```

The error :

{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: dependencyObject"}

I get this when using immediate window

```
    ?this.GetType()
{Name = "HandOverListPage" FullName = "QP_Truck.Pages.HandOverListPage"}
    [System.RuntimeType]: {Name = "HandOverListPage" FullName = "QP_Truck.Pages.HandOverListPage"}
    base {System.Reflection.MemberInfo}: {Name = "HandOverListPage" FullName = "QP_Truck.Pages.HandOverListPage"}
    Assembly: {QP Truck, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
    AssemblyQualifiedName: "QP_Truck.Pages.HandOverListPage, QP Truck, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    Attributes: Public | BeforeFieldInit
    BaseType: {Name = "Page" FullName = "System.Windows.Controls.Page"}
    ContainsGenericParameters: false
    DeclaringMethod: 'this.GetType().DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    DeclaringType: null
    FullName: "QP_Truck.Pages.HandOverListPage"
    GenericParameterAttributes: 'this.GetType().GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericParameterPosition: 'this.GetType().GenericParameterPosition' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GUID: {93eb30b9-a64e-3c6b-9182-0f93582d188d}
    HasElementType: false
    IsAbstract: false
    IsAnsiClass: true
    IsArray: false
    IsAutoClass: false
    IsAutoLayout: true
    IsByRef: false
    IsClass: true
    IsCOMObject: false
    IsContextful: false
    IsEnum: false
    IsExplicitLayout: false
    IsGenericParameter: false
    IsGenericType: false
    IsGenericTypeDefinition: false
    IsImport: false
    IsInterface: false
    IsLayoutSequential: false
    IsMarshalByRef: false
    IsNested: false
    IsNestedAssembly: false
    IsNestedFamANDAssem: false
    IsNestedFamily: false
    IsNestedFamORAssem: false
    IsNestedPrivate: false
    IsNestedPublic: false
    IsNotPublic: false
    IsPointer: false
    IsPrimitive: false
    IsPublic: true
    IsSealed: false
    IsSerializable: false
    IsSpecialName: false
    IsUnicodeClass: false
    IsValueType: false
    IsVisible: true
    MemberType: TypeInfo
    Module: {QP Truck.exe}
    Namespace: "QP_Truck.Pages"
    ReflectedType: null
    StructLayoutAttribute: {System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute}
    TypeHandle: {System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
    TypeInitializer: null
    UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "HandOverListPage" FullName = "QP_Truck.Pages.HandOverListPage"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try **Owner** property, you have to assign it.

Sample:

```
public Activity ShowLookUp(Window owner)
{
     ActivityLookUp lookup = new ActivityLookUp();
     lookup.Owner = owner;
     lookup.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand this. Why is this a better solution than `Window.GetWindow`? Can you provide some more explanation?

Comment: I'm not saying that this is better solution. This is just the way i solve the problem.

Comment: I agree - the page doesn't have an owner by magic, you'll have to set its owner explicitly.

Answer (score 18):

**Is the code that you posted in your constructor method?**

The parent of a `UserControl` is always null in its constructor, so `this.Parent` is returning a null reference. Thus,  calling `Window.GetWindow(this.Parent)` raises an `ArgumentNullException` because the dependency object that you specified has not been created yet.

To fix this, you need to place the code in the `Initialized` event handler. When this event is raised, you can be sure that the `UserControl` has been created.

Comment: I have added the output from the immediate window in my post now.

Comment: This works for me. And should probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is exactly the reason i suspect why I can never get parent window. +1

Comment: I had to call it in `Loaded` rather than `Initialized`, in my situation. WPF may run Loaded multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

What context are you in when you call `this.Parent`?  Are you expecting `this` to be a reference to the `page` object?  From the code sample you've added, that won't be the case.  I would suggest you put a breakpoint at the `Window.GetWindow` line and do `?this.GetType()` in the immediate window to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Tag can be useful sometimes.

Why not try this.

```
// "this" is your Window
YourFrame.Content = new YourPage() { Tag = this };
```

and in your Page, try this

```
Window w = (Window)this.Tag;
// and do all the Window wonders
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Though there are acceptable answers listed, they all seem to be way over complicating the matter.

A Page has no parent, but as a Page is only a page and not a window calling get window on itself will return the window reference and not the page, thus all you need is;

```
Window w = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

Simply omit the .Parent

Answer (score 0):

You can use different options:

From the Code Behind of the **Child** UserControl

- VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this)
- LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(this)
- this.Parent
- Window.GetWindow(this); → if you want the container Window

But all of them will return null if called in the constructor, because the initialization of the child happen before attaching the control to the visual tree.

So you have to call them **after** the child User Control has completed it's loading.

```
public MyChildUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    //Postponing the retrieval of the parent using the OnLoaded event
    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        var p = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);

        while (!(ucParent is UserControl))
        {
            ucParent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject) this);
        }



        _parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
        /// whatever you are going to do with parent window
    };
}
```

As this guy https://stackoverflow.com/a/39477256/196210