# User Control as components. No access to Parent Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am learning WPF and the MVVM pattern, and I may be implementing things incorrectly.

I want to build out components for my app's windows using User Control objects, where components could be used across Windows. For an example I have a NewUnitUserControl that I intend to use as the only component for a dialog window, and also as a component for the MainWindow.

NewUnitUserControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.Views.UserControls.NewUnitUserControl"
    ...                 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample.Views.UserControls">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Border>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label>Name:</Label>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Unit.Name}" Width="136"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border>
                        <Button Command="{Binding CreateUnitCommand}">Create</Button>
                    </Border>
                    <Border>
                        <Button Command="{Binding CancelCommand}">Cancel</Button>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

NewUnitUserControl.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Sample.Views.UserControls
{
    public partial class NewUnitUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public NewUnitUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NewUnitViewModel nuvm = new NewUnitViewModel();
            DataContext = nuvm;
            if (nuvm.CloseAction == null)
            {
                var window = Window.GetWindow(this); // window evaluates to null 
                                                     // after this line.
                nuvm.CloseAction = new Action(window.Close);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NewUnitViewModel.cs

```
namespace Sample.ViewModels
{
    internal class NewUnitViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //Properties
        private Unit _unit;
        public Unit Unit
        {
            get { return _unit; }
            set { _unit = value; OnPropertyChanged("Unit"); }
        }

        public Action CloseAction { get; set; }

        private ICommand _createUnitCommand;
        public ICommand CreateUnitCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_unitUpdateCommand == null)
                    _unitUpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(param => CreateUnit(), param => true);
                return _unitUpdateCommand;
            }
        }

        private ICommand _cancelCommand;
        public ICommand CancelCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if(_cancelCommand == null)
                    _cancelCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Cancel(), param => true);
                return _cancelCommand;
            }
        }

        //Constructor
        public CreateUnitViewModel()
        {
            _unit = new Models.Unit();
        }

        //Methods
        public void CreateUnit()
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, String.Format("{0} was created.", Unit.Name));
        }

        public void Cancel()
        {
            this.CloseAction();
        }

        #region INotifyProperty Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

NewUnitDialogWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.Views.NewUnitWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample.Views"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Sample.Views.UserControls"
        >
    <controls:NewUnitUserControl />
</Window>
```

NewUnitDialogWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace Sample.Views
{
    public partial class NewUnitWindow : Window
    {
        public NewUnitWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    
    }
}
```

Full Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/ZackDeRose/SimpleRPG)

The problem I'm immediately facing is that with my implementation, I'm unable to access the User Control's parent window using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865659/how-to-close-parent-windows-using-wpf-user-control/32881727) (see the comment in NewUnitUserControl.xaml.cs). I expect the root of my issues is that I'm not understanding the MVVM pattern correctly.

Comment: `NewUnitViewModel cuvm = new NewUnitViewModel(); DataContext = nuvm;` that's a code smell.  Your user control should behave like a control.  Controls do not set their DataContext.  Does the TextBox create an instance of a TextBoxViewModel and set it as it's DataContext?  That would prevent you from binding against it.

Comment: @Will I see your point. I don't see how to create a self-contained reusable "component" via a User Control without setting that User Control's DataContext though. Is there something wrong with my concept of a what constitutes a User Control? Is there a different way of doing this?

Comment: The best way is to represent your application's state through a graph of view models and models.  The root of this object graph is the DataContext of the main window.  Controls are bound to properties of this root.  For example, it may have an observable collection of child view models.  The collection is bound to the ItemsSource of a ListView.  DataTemplates with an ItemType for each type of child are defined, and within them the UserControl designed for that child is placed.  Now when the ListView looks for a DataTemplate of type NewUnitViewModel, it finds the template and poof!

Comment: (continued) The instance of your NewUnitViewModel is now the DataContext of the NewUnitViewModel.  This is all wired up automatically, and your application state has full control of that view model.  Want another new unit?  Slap a new instance into that property bound to a ContentControl's Content DP.  Bam--the correct DataTemplate is found and the view model is wired up to the correct user control.  The save button can be bound to a DP on the UC and that's bound to the root VM.  Click it and that view model knows the NewUnitViewModel that needs to be added to the database. Simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the user control doesn't know who the parent window is yet. Try moving to the Loaded event:

```
private Window _parentWindow = null;
public NewUnitUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += (s, e) => 
    {
        _parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
        /// whatever you are going to do with parent window
    }
}
```

You could also send a message from the button's command action using something like IEventAggregator from the Prism toolkit or IMessenger (I think that is what it is called) from MvvmToolkit.

Comment: This makes my dialog window close on the Cancel button's click. Thanks! In implementing this as a component to my MainWindow, I'm going to want the Cancel button to 'unload' the NewCharacterUserControl from my MainWindow. Should I consider moving the Cancel button's functionality into the parent's View (or View Model) to support different behavior on the button click?

Comment: This is kind of vague, but I would have the usercontrol manage its own actions and the mainwindow manage its own. The user control would handle the data and signal it's finished or canceled. The mainwindow would receive the signal and do what it needs to do, update the main window, persist data, close dialog, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to access the parent window doesnt seem familiar to me.

> var window = Window.GetWindow(this);

Please try the following code. I edited yours so just replace it :)

```
public NewUnitUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CreateUnitViewModel cuvm = new CreateUnitViewModel();
    DataContext = nuvm;
    if (nuvm.CloseAction == null)
    {
        //var window = this.ParentForm; // window evaluates to null 
        //                                     // after this line.
        if(this.ParentForm != null)
        cuvm.CloseAction = new Action(this.ParentForm.Close);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I put this code in, I got the compiler error:

'NewUnitUserControl' does not contain a definition for 'ParentForm' and no extension method 'ParentForm' accepting a first argument of type 'NewUnitUserControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I missing something?

Comment: It shouldnt be an error because of missing imports. Are you using the right Reference DLLs ? You should have at least System.Windows.Forms as a reference. Also you should use it like this: "using System.Windows.Forms;" Is your UserControl located inside this namespace or is it a custom class you have created? Please also keep in mind that your NewUnitUserControl has to be placed to a Form. Another Problem could be your .NET Framework Version. I`m using version 4+. In some earlier versions it might not be implemented. Hope I gave you some hints.